# Primefaces programmatically create a FeedReader

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm designing a dashboard with programmatically controlled panels (like iGoogle). So far, so good. In some of the panels I want to show feeds, so I'm using p:feedReader.

If I create a page with a panel with a feedreader inside, it work ok. So I'm using the correct libraries.

When I try to create a feedreader programmatically, it doesn't show the feed titles and content.

My test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css" />
        <title>Test Panel</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{panelBean.Init}" />
        <h:form id="frmPortal">

            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />

            <p:panel id="head" style="width: 1900; height: 100px; border: none; background: transparent;">

            </p:panel>

        <p:commandButton id="Test" value="Test" action="#{panelBean.Test}" style="margin-left: 20px;" />
        <p:commandButton id="Update" value="Update" action="#{panelBean.Test}" style="margin-left: 20px;" update="Feed1"/>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

My Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="panelBean")
@ViewScoped
public class PanelBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 403660770777505739L;
    private boolean renderPanel;
    private FeedReader feedReader;

    public void Init() {
        UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
        UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent("frmPortal");

        if (component == null) {
            System.out.println("Component is null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Component is NOT null");
            Panel p = new Panel();
            p.setClosable(true);
            p.setHeader("Test");
            p.setId("Panel1");
            p.setVisible(true);

            feedReader = new FeedReader();
            feedReader.setId("Feed1");
            feedReader.setRendered(true);
            feedReader.setSize(5);
            feedReader.setValue("http://barrapunto.com/barrapunto.rss");
            feedReader.setVar("feed");

            HtmlOutputText outPutText = new HtmlOutputText();
            outPutText.setValue("#{feed.title}");
            p.getChildren().add(feedReader);            

            component.getChildren().add(p);

            RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
            context.update("frmPortal");
        }
        renderPanel = true;
    }

    public boolean isRenderPanel() {
        return renderPanel;
    }

    public void setRenderPanel(boolean renderPanel) {
        this.renderPanel = renderPanel;
    }

    public void Test() {
        UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
        UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent("frmPortal");

        if (component == null) {
             System.out.println("Component is null");
        } else {

             System.out.println(component.getChildren().get(0).getId());
             System.out.println(component.getChildren().get(1).getId());
             System.out.println(component.getChildren().get(2).getId());
             System.out.println(component.getChildren().get(3).getId());
             System.out.println(component.getChildren().get(4).getId());
             Panel panel = (Panel) component.getChildren().get(4);

             FeedReader feed = (FeedReader) panel.getChildren().get(0);
             if (feed == null) {
                  System.out.println("FeedReader is null");
             } else {
                  System.out.println(feed.getId() + " - Size: " + feed.getSize() + " - Value: " + feed.getValue() + " - Var: " + feed.getVar());
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please answer your question in answers sections not in the question.

Comment: I moved your solution to its own community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
<h:form id="frmPortal">

    <p:panelGrid id="panelGrid" columns="1">
     <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />

    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton id="Test" value="Test" action="#{panelBean.Test}" style="margin-left: 20px;" />
    <p:commandButton id="Update" value="Update" action="#{panelBean.Test}" style="margin-left: 20px;" update="Feed1"/>

</h:form>
```

extended backing bean by @Augusto code:

```
public void Init(){
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent("frmPortal");

    if (component != null) {
        p = new Panel();
        p.setClosable(true);
        p.setHeader("Test");
        p.setId("Panel1");
        p.setVisible(true);

        feedReader = new FeedReader();
        feedReader.setId("Feed1");
        feedReader.setRendered(true);
        feedReader.setSize(5);
        feedReader.setValue("http://barrapunto.com/barrapunto.rss");
        feedReader.setVar("feed");  

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();

        HtmlOutputText outputText = new HtmlOutputText();
        outputText.setId("Header");
        ValueExpression valueExpression = context.getApplication()
        .getExpressionFactory()
        .createValueExpression(elContext, "#{feed.title}", Object.class);
        outputText.setValueExpression("value", valueExpression);
        p.getChildren().add(feedReader);            
        component.getChildren().add(p);

        RequestContext reqContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  

        reqContext.update("Feed1");
    }
}
```

If it not working please try without a feedreader. Meanwhile Why use only one feed reader and many panels?

Comment: I added a definition of p variable: Panel p = new Panel(); before p.setClosable(true);
The error is javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with expression "Feed1" referenced from "frmPortal:Update".
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)


I added the: <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{panelBean.Init}" /> tomake the bean create the panel & feed but gives the same error because component is null. Thank you.

Comment: I'm planning to use more than one panel, but that part works ok. Even with widgets in the panels. My problem is with feedreader, that's why i'm testing in only one panel. Once I have it working, I will use it in the dashboard. Thank you.

Comment: I extended backing bean code by according your code. If cannot answer your question, can you edit my answer? Thanks for response!

Comment: I don't know if Augusto answer was different from yours, but in case I moved it from the question to a community wiki post. If it's now a duplicate answer, please tell me and I'll delete the community wiki altogether.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

**Thank you everybody and specially to Herry. I found the answer. Here it goes:**

```
public void Init() {

    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent("frmPortal");

    if (component == null) {
        System.out.println("Component is null");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Component is NOT null");
        p = new Panel();
        p.setClosable(true);
        p.setHeader("Test");
        p.setId("Panel1");
        p.setVisible(true);

        feedReader = new FeedReader();
        feedReader.setId("Feed1");
        feedReader.setRendered(true);
        feedReader.setSize(5);
        feedReader.setValue("http://barrapunto.com/barrapunto.rss");
        feedReader.setVar("feed");

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();

        HtmlOutputText outputText = new HtmlOutputText();
        outputText.setId("Header");
        ValueExpression valueExpression = context.getApplication()
                .getExpressionFactory()
                .createValueExpression(elContext, "#{feed.title}", Object.class);
        outputText.setValueExpression("value", valueExpression);
//          outputText.setValue("#{feed.title}");
        feedReader.getChildren().add(outputText);

        p.getChildren().add(feedReader);            

        component.getChildren().add(p);

        RequestContext reqContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  

        reqContext.update("Feed1");
    }

    renderPanel = true;
}
```